# Histogram with circles showing frequency

Tags: graphics, histograms

Here's a rough demonstration of what I'm doing:

```
Histogram[{1, 1, 3}, {Range[0.5, 3.5, 1]}, Axes -> {True, False}, ChartElements -> Graphics[Disk[]]]
```

[image: Histogram with circles for frequency]

How do I get the circles to be the exact right size so that a frequency of $x$ is represented by exactly $x$ full circles?

Comment: Maybe `Histogram[{1, 1, 3}, {Range[0.5, 3.5, 1]}, Axes -> {True, False}, 
 ChartElements -> {Graphics[Disk[]], {1, 1}}]`?

Comment: Thanks! If you want to pose it as an answer, I'll accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Carl Woll's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148623/histogram-with-circles-showing-frequency#comment398959_148623) comment:

```
Histogram[{1, 1, 3}, {Range[0.5, 3.5, 1]}, Axes -> {True, False}, ChartElements -> {Graphics[Disk[]], {1, 1}}]
```

[image]

He used the following settings of the [`ChartElements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartElements.html) function:

[image]